# Can a 2013 Nissan tailgate handle fit on a 2012 model?

Tags: camera, backup-camera, titan, tailgate

Looking to install a backup camera on a 2012 Titan I do not like the license place camera setup and found on eBay you can get a tailgate handle for 2013 model. From my research involving the tailgate I can find no differences and the style looks the same, but I think the only reason this doesn't say for anything before 2013 because it wasn't an offered feature. Can anyone verify if a 2013 tailgate handle will fit a 2012 model?

Picture of item:

[image]

[Link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/fits-Nissan-Titan-2013-2014-2015-Tailgate-Handle-Textured-Black-with-Camera-Hole/111902612703?hash=item1a0dea5cdf:g:VVEAAOSwKtVWvnSJ:rk:9:pf:0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pictures I've seen, the two handles (2012 v 2013) are totally different. Here's an image of the 2012 handle:

[image: Image pulled from RockAuto.com - for illustration purposes only.]

My suggestion to you is, it won't work.